# Are using Parameters necessary?

Tags: javascript, parameters

For example:

```
    function test(x) {
       alert("This is a " + x);
    }

    test("test");
```

I honestly do not see the point in it (it's probably because I don't have much knowledge on this subject), but if you could explain a bit, that would be magnificent!

Comment: "Necessary" except when they're not. At times, you need them, others no.

Comment: Honestly, this is a bit of a basic lack of programming knowledge.  You might want to have a look at this: http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/javascript-101-week-2-functions-encapsulation-augmentation/

Comment: This is a daft question.

Comment: you don't see the point in what? What is your question you are actually asking?

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want.......

Answer (score 2):

> There are four patterns of invocation in JavaScript: the method
>   invocation pattern, the function invocation pattern, the constructor invocation pattern, and the apply
>   invocation pattern. The patterns differ in how the bonus parameter this is initialized.
>   The invocation operator is a pair of parentheses that follow any expression that produces a function value. The
>   parentheses can contain zero or more expressions, separated by commas. Each expression produces one
>   argument value. Each of the argument values will be assigned to the function's parameter names. **There is no
>   runtime error when the number of arguments and the number of parameters do not match. If there are too
>   many argument values, the extra argument values will be ignored. If there are too few argument values, the
>   undefined value will be substituted for the missing values.** There is no type checking on the argument
>   values: any type of value can be passed to any parameter.

*"JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. Copyright 2008 Yahoo! Inc.,
978-0-596-51774-8."*

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't support function overloading, but everytime a function is called the `arguments` variable is set with an array of all the parameters that are passed, even if they're not named in the function declaration. For example:

```
function prod() {
    var res = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        res *= arguments[i];
    return res;
}
var p = prod(5, 3, 7);    // => 105
```

Note: `arguments` actually isn't an `Array` object, i.e. it doesn't have the same `prototype`. But it can easily converted to an array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameters allow substition: instead of writing the same code over and over, we re-use it, with our own values. In *your* example, the method doesn't do much, so there's little advantage.

But with only a minor tweak, it might make more sense:

```
function test(x) {
    var y = x * 2
    if (y === NaN) {
        alert("That was no number!");
    } else {
        alert("Multiplied by 2, " + x + " is " + y);
    }
}
```

We wouldn't want to write that every time we wanted to run that code, substituting our values:

```
var y = "test" * 2
if (y === NaN) {
    alert("That was no number!");
} else {
    alert("Multiplied by 2, test is " + y);
}

var y = 5 * 2
if (y === NaN) {
    alert("That was no number!");
} else {
    alert("Multiplied by 5, test is " + y);
}
```

*Note: The value might come from a form, a database, a web service, etc.* 
*In our example it's hardcoded, but in real life, this is less likely.*

Instead we create the `test` method, generic code that handles the cases we care about.

Then we can write:

```
test("test");
test(5);
```

If what we needed to do *changes*, we change a single `test` method, rather than finding all the places in the code we used the same logic. This makes program maintenance and testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

This will work without prameter check over here

## Demo

Note : if you are using that parameter in your function then it's better to pass it in the function call otherwise it remains "undefined"...

**Final conculsion**

```
function test(a) 
{     
  alert(a); 
}  

test(1); // outputs 1 
test(); // outputs undefined
```

when you dont pass the value for argument thatn it Set to undefined. You don't get an exception. It can be a convenient method to make your function more versatile in certain situations. Undefined evaluates to false, so you can check whether or not a value was passed in

Comment: I don't understand what you're proving with this answer?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - without parameter you can call the function but the value of parameter is "undefined" thats the problem if you are using that parameter further in you code....

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think Pranay is answering the question "can I call a method without parameters even though the method takes them", whereas the OP is asking... um... something else, but not that.

Comment: @PranayRana I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because the OP is asking a far more basic question.

Comment: @DaveNewton - may be but if you read question "Are using Parameters necessary?"...that what i answered because rest of the thing are not that much clear ...

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yes, I see that; I didn't say it was wrong, just misleading to someone who may not really understand the meaning being parsed here. Also, I did not downvote either, I just think the answer needed a "fuller" answer.

Comment: @PranayRana I understand what you answered--I just don't think that's what they're asking. It's a poorly-worded question; I'm just guessing :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Gotcha. I'm not really sure either :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - but downvote to answer is not fair........because i m answer the question

Comment: @PranayRana Nothing we can do about who decides to downvote, or why. There are many reasons why someone might downvote an answer--could be technical ("this is wrong"), could be philosophical ("I disagree"), could be procedural ("I don't think this answers the question"), could be personal ("I don't like you"), could be usage ("This is hard to read"), could be anything. That's the nature of SO--it's fair to ask for a reason for a downvote, but there's nothing to enforce making a downvoter * answer* the question. Such is life.